# Trained Spam Machine Learning Classifier/Model

Tags: machine-learning, spam-prevention

I have a list of sentences about 17 million. I need to identify sentence as spam/ham/unsure. Are there trained models present on the internet to which I could just feed in my data as a "test" set and the system would classify my sentence as spam/ham ?

**Note**: The sentences aren't e-mails.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Bayesian Spam Filtering, take a look at this article pretty nice to understand the theory http://robotics.stanford.edu/users/sahami/papers-dir/spam.pdf